# Combine VBA codes

Tags: excel, vba

I  have a huge spreadsheet, I want column L to generate an email for preferences if "Initiated" is selected from the drop down.
Column M I want to generate a different email if "Ordered" is selected from the drop down.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm basically using the same code twice, but will change the email that is produced.  Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

```vb
'Preferences
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("L:L"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "Initiated" Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub



'Truck
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("M:M"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "Ordered" Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is expand the range `xRg` refers to.

```
Option Explicit

'Preferences or Truck
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("L:M"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "Initiated" Or Target.Value = "Ordered" Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Const VAL_INITIATED = "Initiated"
Const VAL_ORDERED = "Ordered"

'Preferences
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Me.Range("L:M"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If Target.Value = VAL_INITIATED Or _
       Target.Value = VAL_ORDERED Then
        Mail_small_Text_Outlook Target
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(rng As Range)
    
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'specific formatting goes here
    If rng.Value = VAL_INITIATED Then
        'add mail setup for initiated
        xOutMail.Body = "Something was initiated"
    ElseIf rng.Value = VAL_ORDERED Then
        'add mail setup for ordered
        xOutMail.Body = "Something was ordered"
    End If
    
    'common formatting goes here
    With xOutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*Expanding the intersection range will not work as the options are mutually exclusive.*
Suggest to use the [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement)

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Rem Validate Target Value & Location
    Select Case Target.Value
    
    Case "Initiated"
        If Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
    Case "Ordered"
        If Intersect(Target, Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Case Else
        Exit Sub
    
    End Select

    Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Target.Value)
    
End Sub
```

Then in the `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` procedure, replace these lines:

`Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()`
`.Subject = "send by cell value test"`

with these:

`Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(sValue As String)`
`.Subject = "send by " & sValue`  *(Change as required)*